# Loadrunner siebel

Tags: loadrunner, siebel

I have red a lot about loadrunner online and quite often I come across Siebel. People say they use Siebel to record i.e. But is Siebel something that is used also on regular web applications? Not being the Oracle Siebel product under test? Is this Siebel some magic protocol that fits other platforms as well?
What is the deal with Siebel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You often see questions related to Siebel because it is a very correlation intensive protocol and the vast majority of users of LoadRunner are weak in this core foundation mechanical tool skill, the collection of dynamic data and presentation back into the script.

Siebel uses a structure called the Siebel Star array, which is substantial in size and requires correlation for proper handling of the Seibel web client.   Siebel has available a correlation library which can handle a good portion of the Star Array challenges, but manual skills are still required on top of this to manage dynamic elements which are outside of the star-array structure.  It is my understanding that Siebel charges for the use of this library, so if one is technically competent with correlation then you should be able to construct your own correlation rules to handle repeated Siebel script development activities.

Answer (score 0):

Siebel-Web is a protocol in LoadRunner, probably created to handle web-services/pages created with the [Siebel CRM platform](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/applications/siebel/overview/index.html).

Siebel-Web is HTTP based, but having seen the HTML responses from Siebel CRM services I strongly recommend using the Siebel-Web protocol instead of HTML/HTTP protocol ...

Comment: I am not in a place where I need to record against a Siebel CRM platform, but I am just generally curious if Siebel-web protocol could provide me something better than regular http/html protocol? Can I paste Siebel web recorded scripts directly into an empty http/html script?

Comment: I don't think you can mix Siebel-Web and HTTP protocols, unless you have a Multi-Protocol script as the base. I've never tried this so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Siebel-Web is a proprietary protocol that isn't used outside of the Oracle Siebel CRM context. So, using this for a different website would not be beneficial and only complicate your LoadRunner approach.

Answer (score -1):

Performance testing Siebel CRM application is definitely not straightforward as it's a complicated web application which uses Internet explorer's high interactivity framework and the data exchanged required good amount of parsing.

Oracle provides a Correlation Library (ssdtcorr.dll) along with Siebel installation to deal with correlation of LR vugen scripts for Siebel protocol. [Click here for more info](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E05553_01/books/TestGuide/TestGuide_AutoPerformTest6.html). But that doesn't always help.

Additional best practices can be found [here.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31104_02/books/TestGuide/TestGuide_DevelopTests11.html#wp131105)